# C# database access error "there is already an open DataReader"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I use C# to create an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API REST service with Minimal API.

I try to access a SQL Server but I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: there is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first.

I've tried dispose and "Using" statement...

Here is the code:

Program.cs:

```
// REST Endpoint
//
app.MapGet("/Inquiry/test/{InquiyId}", async (CCTPDbContext db, HttpRequest request) =>
{
    int InquiryId = Int32.Parse(request.RouteValues["InquiyId"].ToString());

    Inquiry? inquiryZ = await (from i in db.Inquiry
                               where i.Id == InquiryId
                               select new Inquiry
                                      {
                                          Id = i.Id,
                                          LocationId = i.LocationId,
                                          Description = i.Description,
                                          DateFrom = i.DateFrom,
                                          DateTo = i.DateTo,
                       
                                          // here I get the error
                                          LocationLautLocationId = new Location().GetLocationById(db, i.LocationId),
                                          ....
                                      }
}
```

`Location.cs`:

This is what I have tested without success:

```
public Location? GetLocationById (CCTPDbContext db, int locationId)
{
    Location? loc = null;

    // Location? loc = db.Location.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);

    // using (CCTPDbContext dbcontext = db )
    // using (db)
    // { 
    //     Location? loc = dbcontext.Location.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);
    //     loc = dbcontext.Location.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);
    //     loc = db.Location.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);
    //     var x = db.Location.Where (l => l.Id == locationId).ToList();
    //     var records = dbcontext.Location.Where(r => r.SomeProperty == "some value").ToList();


  //return loc;

  // } 

  loc = (from l in db.Location
      where l.Id == locationId
      select new Location
      {
        Id = l.Id, //FK
        Name = l.Name,
        Description = l.Description

      }).FirstOrDefault<Location>();

  return loc;
}
```

Comment: Question looks fine to me. It's clear what's happening and why.

Comment: Do you not have an Inquiry.Location navigation property?

Comment: You also could `Include` method of the DbSet to avoid executing multiple database queries at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question

```
LocationLautLocationId = new Location().GetLocationById(db, i.LocationId)
```

causes another read to the database while the first is still in progress. There are a few solutions. Based on the fact you're only bringing back one record, I would materialize the results before the troublesome query like this:

```
Inquiry? inquiryZ = (await (from i in db.Inquiry
                     where i.Id == InquiyId)).SingleOrDefault();

// Error handling if null is returned (no match)

var newInquiry = inquiryZ.Select(i => 
    new Inquiry
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        LocationId = i.LocationId,
        Description = i.Description,
        DateFrom = i.DateFrom,
        DateTo = i.DateTo,                       
        LocationLautLocationId = new Location().GetLocationById(db, i.LocationId)
    });
```